# PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, syntax

Cant figuer out the problem with my code. Theres a syntax error,and i just cant spot it
Checked it here - http://phpcodechecker.com/ , and got this as an answer -

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$val[''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in your code on
>   line 10

Here is the code -

```html
<?php
  include "products.php";

  foreach($products as $key=>$val)
  {
   echo '<div style="float:right;text-align:center;margin:20px;">';
   echo '<IMG src="img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].'" WIDTH="94" HEIGHT="94" BORDER="0" ALT=""><br />';
   echo $val['name'].'<br />';
   echo '₪ '.$val['price'].'<br />';
   echo '<a onmousedown="parent.AddItemToCart(''.$val['id'].'' ,''.$val['name'].'','img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].'','.$val['price'].'')"></a><br/>';
   echo '</div>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: The issue is your double single quotes around your concats and when using them for empty values. I think you meant to escape the first ones, i.e. `\''`.

Comment: Yes because you're escaping the string in line 10.

Comment: I suggest you have a look through the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on how to use strings in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The unescaped `'` terminates the string before you want it to. Try:

```
echo '<a onmousedown="parent.AddItemToCart(\''.$val['id'].'\' ,\''.$val['name'].'\','img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].'','.$val['price'].'\')"></a><br/>';
```

or use double quotes:

```
echo "<a onmousedown=\"parent.AddItemToCart('".$val['id']."' ,'".$val['name']."','img/".$val['category']."/".$val['image']."','.$val['price']."')\"></a><br/>';
```

**Reason:** The reason of this happening, is that you use `'` to start and end your string, but your string also contains the `'` character. This way the string  ends at the position you enter `'` and is confused by the following symbols. To prevent this, you escape the symbols using a backslash `\` like so: `'some string containing a \' character'`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
echo '<a onmousedown="parent.AddItemToCart(''.$val['id'].'' ,''.$val['name'].'','img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].'','.$val['price'].'')"></a><br/>';
```

to

```
$imgtag = 'img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'];
echo '<a onmousedown="parent.AddItemToCart(\''.$val['id'].'\',\''.$val['name'].'\',\''.$imgtag.'\',\''.$val['price'].'\')"></a><br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
echo '<a onmousedown="parent.AddItemToCart(''.$val['id'].'' ,''.$val['name'].'','img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].'','.$val['price'].'')"></a><br/>';
```

For this:

```
echo "<a onmousedown='parent.AddItemToCart(".$val['id']. ',' .$val['name']. ',img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].','.$val['price'].")></a><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code with given code

```
<?php
    include "products.php";

    foreach($products as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo '<div style="float:right;text-align:center;margin:20px;">';
        echo '<IMG src="img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].'" WIDTH="94" HEIGHT="94" BORDER="0" ALT=""><br />';
        echo $val['name'].'<br />';
        echo '₪ '.$val['price'].'<br />';
        echo '<a onmousedown="parent.AddItemToCart('.$val['id'].','.$val['name'].'','img/'.$val['category'].'/'.$val['image'].','.$val['price'].')"></a><br/>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```